# Better way to create/update records (and associated records) for self referential association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord

I need to know the better way of creating/updating records for self-referential association.

I have a model called as `Template` and a `self-referential` `has_many :through` association with this model:

```
has_many :related_templates, :foreign_key => :parent_id
has_many :children, :through => :related_templates, :source => :child

has_many :inverse_related_templates, class_name: "RelatedTemplate", :foreign_key => :child_id
has_many :parents, :through => :inverse_related_templates, :source => :parent
```

Such that `RelatedTemplates` is a join model.

For the `new` form:

1) Fill up the `parent template` details

2) Add `child templates` either by creating a new template in the same form or add the existing templates as child template to this parent template.

For the `edit` form:

1) Display the details of the `parent template`.

2) Edit `child template` details which are already assigned to it. User should also be able to `edit` the details of the already associated templates.

Since the form is same for new and edit. User can also `create` a new  or `add` from the existing ones in the edit page as well.

My `create` method is like this:

```
def create
  Template.transaction do
    parent_template = Template.new template_params
    if parent_template.save
      children_templates = []
      # if params of new templates are sent
      if params[:template][:children_attributes].present?
        new_templates = params[:template][:children_attributes]
        new_templates.each do |child|
          template = Template.new(attrs)
          template.save
          children_templates << template
        end
      end
      # if params of existing templates are sent
      if params[:template][:existingChildTemplates].present?
        existing_ids = params[:template][:existingChildTemplates]
        children_templates << Template.where(id: existing_ids)
      end
      parent_template.children << children_templates
      render json: { success: true, template_id: parent_template.id, message: "Created Successfully" }
    else
      render_422 parent_template, 'Could not save Parent Template.'
    end
  end
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordInvalid => exception
  render json: { success: false, message: "#{exception}" }, status: 500
end
```

Similarly i have written for `update`:

```
def update
  if @template.update_attributes template_params
    if params[:template][:children_attributes].present?
      associated_templates = @template.children
      new_templates = params[:template][:children_attributes]
      new_templates.each do |child|
        unless child[:id].present?
          # if new template added
          associated_templates.build(attrs)
          @template.save
        else
          # if template attributes updated
          new_template_params = child.permit(attrs)
          child_template = associated_templates.where(id: child[:id]).first
          if (child_template[:name] != child[:name]) || (child_template[:role_id] != child[:role_id])
            child_template.update_attributes(new_template_params)
          end
        end
      end
    end
    if params[:template][:existingChildTemplates].present?
      children_templates = []
    # if selected from the existing one
      existing_ids = params[:template][:existingChildTemplates]
      children_templates << Template.where(id: existing_ids)
      @template.children << children_templates
    end
    render json: { success: true, message: 'Updated.' }
  else
    render_422 @template, 'Template could not be updated.'
  end
end
```

**Questions**

1. How to white list children_attributes? Here i'm manually using the `params`. I tried adding `children_attributes: []` in the permit method and `accepts_nested_attributes_for :children` in the model
   But still it is `Unpermitted Parameter`.
2. What should be the better way to write `create/update` methods and also how should i handle the `validation` errors ?